# How to use React hook usestate to link external image

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am learning react hook now. Trying to implement a very simple feature: when users click the button, the website will randomly display a meme image. All images are non-local (i.e. in the form of URL). Here is my code

```
import React from "react"
import memesData from "../memesData.js"

export default function Meme() {


    const [image, setImage] = React.useState("");


    function getMemeImage() {
        const memesArray = memesData.data.memes
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length)
        setImage(memesArray[randomNumber].url)
        console.log(memesArray[randomNumber].url)
    }

    return (
        <main>
            
            <form className="form">     
                <button 
                    className="form--button"
                    onClick={getMemeImage}
                >
                    Get a new meme image 
                </button>
            </form>
            <img src={image} className="meme--image" />
        </main>
    )
}
```

Something is definitely wrong in the  tag. Currently, nothing happens when I click the button. Didn't know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with a sample memesData and it works.
I think the problem is with the form tag because it causes to refresh the page.

Here's a link for my code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-dirac-3oifkn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Here's the code I used:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Meme() {
  const memesData = {
      data: {
        memes: [
           {
             url:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/800px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png"
           },
           {
             url:  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Google_Photos_icon_%282015-2020%29.svg/1200px-Google_Photos_icon_%282015-2020%29.svg.png"
            }
       ]
     }
 };
 const [image, setImage] = React.useState("");

 function getMemeImage() {
    const memesArray = memesData.data.memes;
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * memesArray.length);
    setImage(memesArray[randomNumber].url);
    console.log(memesArray[randomNumber].url);
 }

return (
  <main>
   <button className="form--button" onClick={() => getMemeImage()}>
     Get a new meme image 
   </button>
   <img src={image} alt="img" className="meme--image" />
  </main>
 );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works now. Yep. I change the form tag to div. Very nuanced problem lol!